# could not able to spawn process using ssh

Tags: ssh

My problem looks like the following:

```
ssh -l user_name xxx.xxx.xxx
Password:xxx
Received disconnect from xxxxx(IP): 11: ProcessTunnel: Could not spawn process
```

I have no idea about this problem and cannot resolve it by google.
Hope for the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the answer to this question. The sever was crashed. Thanks god!